# Cambiar nombre de columna ID - Auth Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo un login con laravel, tenia una tabla ya creada.
El problema es que en mi tabla el id tiene otro nombre y al intentar logearme me muestra este error.

"Undefined index: id"

Este es User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable {
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */

protected $primaryKey = 'IdPersonal';

protected $fillable = [
    'nombres', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

Entiendo que tengo que cambiar id por el nombre de la columna que tengo en mi tabla pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y muéstranos el controlador de Login y el modelo User, para entender lo que estás haciendo, pero por favor no agregues imágenes, muéstranos el código como texto.

Comment: Acabo de editarlo.

Comment: Qué versión exacta de 5.5 tienes? me refiero a 5.5.x

Comment: tengo la versión v5.5.14

Answer (score 1):

Si dicho campo es la llave primaria del modelo, entonces simplemente debes cambiar dicho valor en el modelo.

Asumiendo que el campo se llama `custom_id`, agrega lo siguiente en el modelo User.php:

```
/**
 * The primary key for the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'custom_id';
```

Comment: Yo agregaría que aunque esta propiedad se debe indicar explícitamente cuando modificamos el nombre del campo que hace de clave primaria de una tabla, es una buena práctica añadirla en cada modelo, aunque haga referencia a la PK que lleva la tabla relacionada por defecto. Porque así podemos saber con toda certeza que campo hace de PK en cada la tabla relacionada.

Comment: Gracias por responder, justo es lo mismo que hice hace un momento pero sigue sin funcionar y salir lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

con la poca informacion que das es dificl saber bien que necesitas

**1. DB:**

- La tabla no existe.

  > **Solucion:** Migra la tabla. de no tener migraciones, crea las migraciones primero
- La PK no existe o no se asigno a una columna.

  > **Solucion:** Edita la migracion  para crear la columna o modifica la que existe como PK, y luego migra de nuevo la DB
- La PK tiene un nombre diferente al esperado.

  > **Solucion:** Edita la migracion  para cambiar el nombre de la PK, y luego migra de nuevo la DB

**2. Vistas:**

- Las variables del formulario no coincide con el controlador.

  > **Solucion:** edita el nombre de los input del formulario para que coincida con los que espera recibir el controlador

**3. Código:**
esta parte es un poco mas ambigua porque depende de si estas utilizando el login de laravel y modificandolo o creaste tu propio login desde 0:

1. Editando el login de laravel:

   - el error proviene del código inplicado en la autentificación.

     > **Solución 1**: revisa los nombres usados para representar al id en los controladores  de la carpeta
     >
     > > /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/
     >
     > y editalos para que coincida con tus preferencias
     >
     > **Solución 2:** revisa el modelo de User.php que estas usando y verifica que la variable definida en el modelo es igual a la que esta en la base de datos. (segun la informacion que diste, este no deberia ser el problema)
2. creando tu propio login personalizado desde cero.

   - error de codigo.

     > **Solución:** el error peude provenir de cualquiera de tus archivos utilizados para este fin, revisa todo lo visto en los demas soluciones en tus propiso archivos.

PD: intenta mostrar mas informacion relevante para estos casos